# Ubuntu get the last word in a sentence from a text file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu

I have a tab separated text file structured as follows:

```
word0  word1  word2  word3  word4  word5  word6
```

From a linux commond line I want to:

1. Get only word6
2. How would I get only the characters ord6 in word6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AWK can do that :

```
 $ echo "word0 word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6" | awk '{ print $(NF) }'
 word6
```

Comment: work perfectly to get word6 now how would I go a step further and get ord6 or wor from word6

Comment: Pipe this to : `sed -E 's/.(...)./\1/'` and you'll get ord, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple `cut` command as given:
`$cut -d'Press CTRL+v then TAB key to insert tab as delim here' -f6 textfile|cut -c2-

ord6

$`

Check out the man page for the cut command for more.

Ofcourse, there are so many other ways, to do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
awk -F "\t" '{print $NF}' Input.txt
```

Change your delimiter according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
string=$(echo "word0 word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6" | awk '{ print $(NF) }')
echo ${string:3:4}  # echo substring starting at postion3, 4 characters long i.e. ord6
```

or

```
echo ${string[@]#w} # removes the shortest possible match for the regex 
                    # (i.e. w) at the start of the string
```

## for longest match, % & %% to remove the back of a string